# Oracle: Date Format Problems YYYY-MM-DD

Tags: oracle, date, datetime, dbeaver

I have a problem that could seems naive (and could actually be naive) but I cannot solve...

The thing is that I'm trying to insert some data from Pentaho to a Oracle DB and in Pentaho I have my Date in format `YYYY-MM-DD`, but when in Oracle it appears `YYYY-MM-DD 00:00:00`. The point is that the format of the attribute is Date, and when I manually, through SQL, insert data into the table, it happens the same.

```
INSERT INTO TABLE1
VALUES(TO_DATE('2012-02-01','yyyy-mm-dd'))
```

When I visualize the data, I see again `2012-02-01 00:00:00`.
I'm using Dbeaver, and when I go to Properties to see the Date format, it appears `YYYY-MM-DD`, so I don't understand what's happening neither how to solve it.

[image: Dbeaver Snapshot]

Thank you!

Comment: That's because an Oracle `date` **always** contains a time part. It makes perfect sense to display that.

Answer (score 2):

The date format visualized in the oracle depends on the `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` parameter. But please note that oracle does not store the Date in any format but it has its own binary representation for dates.

so you can configure how you want to see dates in your session or at the database level or at an instance level.

At session-level, You can alter `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` as follows:

```
SQL> ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT = 'YYYY-MM-DD';

Session altered.

SQL> SELECT SYSDATE FROM DUAL;

SYSDATE
----------
2020-11-27

SQL> ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT = 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS';

Session altered.

SQL> SELECT SYSDATE FROM DUAL;

SYSDATE
-------------------
2020-11-27 15:17:02

SQL> ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT = 'DD-MON-YYYY';

Session altered.

SQL> SELECT SYSDATE FROM DUAL;

SYSDATE
-----------
27-NOV-2020

SQL>
```

To check for the current value of `NLS_DATE_FORMAT`, You can use the following view:

```
SELECT * FROM NLS_SESSION_PARAMETERS WHERE PARAMETER = 'NLS_DATE_FORMAT';
SELECT * FROM NLS_INSTANCE_PARAMETERS WHERE PARAMETER = 'NLS_DATE_FORMAT';
SELECT * FROM NLS_DATABASE_PARAMETERS WHERE PARAMETER = 'NLS_DATE_FORMAT';
```

Comment: Does the dbeaver IDE use the NLS settings to format its values?

Comment: Yes, You can also change it using `ALTER SESSION` command as shown in the answer.

Comment: Thank you but it doesn't work :(
I don't know why but I still retrieve YYYY-MM-DD 00:00:00 even before doing ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT = 'YYYY-MM-DD'.
And I check the value of NLS_DATE_FORMAT and it's 'YYYY-MM-DD'.

Comment: ALTER SESSION command works in dbeaver - https://github.com/dbeaver/dbeaver/issues/881

Comment: Dbeaver is Java based, i.e. `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` does not apply - unless Dbeaver queries the format internally.

Answer (score 0):

I would not rely on the NLS_DATE_FORMAT nls parameter (what if you have multiple queries which need to output the dates in different formats?). If you need to view your dates in a specific format, use `to_char()`, e.g.:

```
SELECT to_char(date_col, 'dd/mm/yyyy') date_col
FROM   table1;
```